# solving Venn diagram

Tags: probability

A record survey was carried out among $70$ teenagers. The choice was out of three records: $A,G,P$ the result showed that $52$ teenagers liked $A$, $29$ liked $G$, and $37$ liked $P$. It was also found that $24$ like both $A$ and $P$ but not $G$. $11$ liked all $3$ records, $28$ liked both $A$ and $G$, and only one liked $P$ and $G$ but not $A$.

> Find by means of a Venn diagram. How many teenagers liked:
>
> - a) $2$ records only?
> - b) At least $2$ records?
> - c) At least $1$ record?
> - d) One of the records only?
> - e) At most $2$ records?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you drawn the Venn diagram? There is enough information to draw it, don't forget there may be some people who didn't like any record.

Answer (score 2):

There are $8$ separate sets ($8$ colors on the diagram). Denote
$N_0 - $ number of teenagers that don't like anything (lightgray); 
$N_a -$ number of teenagers liked A only (red), 
$N_g -$ number of teenagers liked G only (yellow), 
 
$N_p -$ number of teenagers liked P only (blue), 
$N_{ag}, N_{gp}, N_{ap} -$ $...$ liked $2$ records (accordingly; orange, green, purple), 
$N_{agp} - $ $...$ liked $3$ records (dark part).

[image]

We have system of $8$ equations for $8$ variables:

$
N_0+N_a+N_b+\ldots+N_{agp}=70;\\
N_a+N_{ag}+N_{ap}+N_{agp}=52;\\
N_g+N_{ag}+N_{gp}+N_{agp}=29;\\
N_p+N_{ap}+N_{gp}+N_{agp}=37;\\
N_{ap} = 24;\\
N_{agp}=11;\\
N_{ag}+N_{agp}=28;\\
N_{gp}=1.
$

Now you can figure out each variable; step-by-step; i.e.

$
N_{ag}=28-N_{agp}=28-11=17;\\
N_a=52-N_{ag}-N_{ap}-N_{agp} = 52-17-24-11=0; \text{(red part will be empty set)}\\
\cdots
$

Then apply founded values for question.

a) "$2$ records only" means orange + green + purple;
b) "at least $2$ records" means orange+green+purple+dark;
c) "at least $1$ record" means all but except lightgray;
d) "one of the records" means red + yellow + blue;
c) "at most $2$ records" means all but except dark.

Let's complete it.